# ASP .Net error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. "

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I get the following error when trying to load an RSS feed:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

My code works fine from my local host, error only occurs when i upload it to my dedicated server!

Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim signJ As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    If signJ <> "" Then
        Try
            Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            Dim xdsData As XmlDataSource = New XmlDataSource
            Dim xpath_path As String = String.Empty
            Dim RSS_Feed As String = String.Empty

            xpath_path = "rss/channel/item[title='" & signJ & "']"
            RSS_Feed = "http://feedurl.."

            xmlDoc.Load(RSS_Feed)
            xdsData.Data = xmlDoc.OuterXml
            xdsData.XPath = xpath_path
            rptData.DataSource = xdsData
            rptData.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Error occurs on this line: `xmlDoc.Load(RSS_Feed)`

Real stuck on this one! cheers

Answer (score 1):

We had the same behaviour as Todd Smith mentions. After the upgrade to .Net 3.5 SP1 we got this error.

In our case the reason was the **protection / obfuscation** of our DLLs with Remotesoft Protector.

This is most likely only our problem and not a solution for anyone else. Nevertheless I thought I'd mention it here cause it did cost us some hours to find out.

If you protect, obfuscate your DLLs: disabling that might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this error but have you verified that your security/permissions are set correctly on the dedicated server?

Also you might want to confirm that you can access the feed directly from a browser on the dedicated server.

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/p/675515/675515.aspx) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I get the

> Attempted to read or write protected memory

Error when I install .NET 3.5 **SP1** (so I can develop asp.net mvc apps).

Downgrading to .NET 3.5 without the service pack fixes the error but of course prevents me from doing mvc development. Time to dust off the virtual machine.